# Implementing Private Cloud

Tags: cloud, openstack

I want to implement private cloud for my college using free tools like open nebula etc so where to start? or is there any step by step guide available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building you own cloud with Ubuntu : http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/build-a-cloud

as I have searched and found a very good link about private cloud with Ubuntu.

[Cloud setup with Ubuntu.pdf](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/45/Deploying%20an%20Open%20Source%20Private%20Cloud%20On%20a%20Shoe%20String%20Budget%20Presentation.pdf)

This a PDF document which will explains you step by step process on setup.

Must read links to understand it in a better 
       -    http://www.networkcomputing.com/private-cloud-tech-center/five-steps-to-building-a-private-cloud/240004192

http://www.itworld.com/answers/topic/cloud-computing/question/how-can-i-build-private-cloud

[Ubuntu Official cloud setup](https://web.archive.org/web/20130905102013/http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-cloud)

Answer (score 0):

There is also some documentation updated for each release of OpenStack:

https://docs.openstack.org